# How to add one more value against at the end of each bar with a legend

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How to add one more value at the end of each bar. Also, I need to bind those values with a legend. What I want is  I will explain with an example. If you notice on the right-hand side of the graph I need to show value against each bar. And in the bottom, I want to add one more legend which will bind those values

So, far What I have tried playing with the y-axis formatted. But the issues are

1. The value on the right-hand side is not aligned.
2. I need a way to bind these values from a legend

[image]

This is what I have tried so far

```
arr = [599, 756, 515, 346, 398, 518, 339, 3190, 402, 290]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
      //  marginLeft: 50,
        // width: 450,
   //     marginBottom: 90,
 
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
     
         stackLabels: {
        style: {
          textShadow: false
        },
        
        enabled: true,
         formatter:function() {
          
          return this.total + '<div style="float: right !important; " >   ' + arr[this.x] + '</div>';
           
        } 
      },
    },

    plotOptions: {
       series: {
        stickyTracking: false,
        followPointer: false,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        pointWidth: 20,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: true,
       
          style: {
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
          }
        },
        stacking: true
      },
     
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best solution to achieve the wanted result will be rendering those values as a custom label via using the `SVGRenderer` tool and creating the dummy series and anchor the labels to it - to get the legend binding.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o4p83j9m/

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this;

    chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      if (p.overallLabel) {
        p.overallLabel.destroy();
      }
      let x = chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft + 10, // where 10 is a padding,
        y = p.dataLabel.absoluteBox.y - p.dataLabel.bBox.y,
        opacity = chart.series[2].visible;

      p.overallLabel = chart.renderer.label(arr[p.index], x, y)
        .attr({
          fill: 'orange',
          padding: 3,
          r: 10,
          opacity: opacity ? 1 : 0
        }).add()
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

If something will be unclear - feel free to ask.

Comment: Sebastian Wędzel Can you explain absoluteBox & bBox

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari it's the `point.dataLabel` position - I used it to set the custom label position on the same y level as the data label is.

Comment: Sebastian Wędzel  My question is why we didn't do like this y = p.dataLabel.y - p.dataLabel.y,  If I take y directly from data label is it an issue?

Comment: Also, when I hover over the Overall legend why other series are getting blurred?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari `p.dataLabel.y` is not a wanted y position. Absolute box is a calculated position regarding to chart plot.

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari second question: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.states.inactive.enabled

Comment: Sebastian Wędzel I have one last final question. I am using Highcharts 7.0.1 and these methods absoluteBox & Box are only available in Highcharts 8.1.1 and above. I tried to check the source of the method https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blame/b3f1e753a8dc34b0f3751456617618c4e8e9c2a1/js/Extensions/OverlappingDataLabels.js#L79 but didn't get much idea. Any idea how can I workaround in 7.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/ma4j6dkq/12/

Comment: Calculating the y as `y = p.dataLabel.alignAttr.y + chart.plotTop,` gives same output: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h07bte43/

Comment: Sebastian Wedzel Thanks a lot